# PageBlockSection - different Cols in each row

Tags: visualforce

May I know the best possible option to build the below table structure. I tried with PageGrid, but its not working, then I tried with html table, still its not working. I have 2 rows with 5 columns and 3rd row with single column.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PageblockSection with multirow muti columns](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101822/pageblocksection-with-multirow-muti-columns)

Comment: use the colspan class on the column just like regular html. And please do not post the same question multiple time. You can edit your original question if needed

Comment: Sorry, I'm new i couldn't find my orginal question to re-posted. Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible to achieve directly in HTML. You will need JS support to dynamically render the table.

> HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">

</div>
```

> JS

```
var integerArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1];
var dynamicTable = '';
for (index = 0; index < integerArray.length; index++) {
    value = integerArray[index];
    dynamicTable += '<div class="row">';
    var columnWidth = 12 / value;
    for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        dynamicTable += '<div class="col-md-' + columnWidth + ' ">'+i+'</div>';
    }
    dynamicTable += '</div>';

};

$(".container-fluid").append(dynamicTable);
```

I am assuming you know how to import jQuery and bootstrap libraries.

Bootstrap divides the whole screen into 12 sections and renders it properly based on your columns. However, if you want to divide your row into 5 columns, I would suggest to use percentage width. Something like this

```
var columnWidth = 100 / value;
        for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            dynamicTable += '<div style="width:' + columnWidth + ' %">'+i+'</div>';
        }
```

Comment: Not sure where you are coming from but `colspan="x"` on the row that needs to span all columns works just fine

Comment: I didn't know that. Something learnt today :)